# Javascript, passing my string as an argument turns it to a 0

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I'm using scrollmagic.io and am making an anchor navigation menu. I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/wiki/Tutorial-:-Anchor-Navigation). The scroll works! Except it was scrolling back to the beginning and not to the page it should be at.

Here is my code:

```
// init controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// animate scroll instead of a jump
controller.scrollTo(function(target) {
  console.log('scroooooll');
  console.log('target = '+target); // THIS IS PRINTING 0
  console.log(typeof(target));
  /* Commenting out what it should do for simplicity. */
});

// scroll action when you click the nav links
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('href'); // get the href of clicked link
  if ($(id).length > 0) { // not empty links
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent normal link action

    // this is the function call
    console.log('click');
    console.log('id = '+id); // IT PRINTS CORRECT HERE
    console.log(typeof(id));
    controller.scrollTo(id); // scroll on click

    // update the URL
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
      history.pushState("", document.title, id);
    }
  }
});
```

And here is the output of my console log:

```
click
id = #{the-href-value}
string
scroooooll
target = 0
number
```

My Javascript is pretty rusty, but this doesn't seem right to me. Why is it changing my variable from a string to a 0 when I pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in the browser?

Comment: I am using my browser. The output is what the console log prints when I click the link. I'm trying to figure out where the 0 comes from.

Comment: I'm talking about using the debugger, not just `console.log`. For example the [chrome debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/).

Comment: The first time you call `controller.scrollTo` you're passing it a function, the second time just an id. I don't know which one is right, but I imagine that's the reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: The way i understand it, it's supposed to be the scroll position of the target element. so it's supposed to be a number. 0 to me means you're giving it an id that doesn't match up with an element on the page, or the plugin is unable to get a y position for said element for whatever reason.

Comment: Fo the y position, if I put the string of one of the elements I want to scroll it will scroll to that element so it doesn't necessarily have to be a number. I mainly can't figure out why target is 0 when I call scrollTo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documents:

> "This function will be used for future scroll position modifications.
>   This provides a way for you to change the behaviour of scrolling and
>   adding new behaviour like animation. The function receives the new
>   scroll position as a parameter and a reference to the container
>   element using this. It may also optionally receive an optional
>   additional parameter (see below)"

So, the first parameter is passed by controller.
You will get your parameter after that.

http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Controller.html#scrollTo

Try printing `console.log(args);`

```
controller.scrollTo(function(scrollPos, targetHrefISent) {
  console.log('scroooooll');
  console.log('target = '+targetHrefISent); // THIS IS PRINTING 0
  console.log(typeof(targetHrefISent));
  /* Commenting out what it should do for simplicity. */
});
```

Comment: This kinda helped. I passed an arbitrary number as my first parameter and it works now! Thanks